# can't use ical-generator as a browser-only library

Tags: javascript, node.js, icalendar

I think my question is pretty stupid but I am blocking on it,  it's for a year-end project.
I have to use ical-generator (https://github.com/sebbo2002/ical-generator#readme) to generate an ics file, but I should not use it with nodeJs but only in the client part, but I don't know how to do it
if someone have just an advice it would be really great.

thank's all

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it with `npm` anyway. It looks like they have webpack configuration, so chances are that after download, there will be a minified webpack build in your `node_modules` that you can use as-is.